# How does Windows know what version of Visual Studio a .sln file relates to?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

If I have a VS 2005 solution then it shows up as "Version: Visual Studio 2005". If I have a VS 2010 solution, the sln file shows up as related to that.

Both of them have a .sln suffix.  So how does Windows know which version of VS to open it with?

Comment: For me, the more amazing thing is that if you edit the version number at the top of a .sln file, the icon displayed in the Explorer window changes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It uses Property Handler and Icon Handler shell extensions (part of the Visual Studio Version Selector)
These are registered by the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.sln` (referenced by `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sln`)

When you open the file, it runs `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe" "%1"`, which reads the version from the `.sln` file and open the correct version.

Comment: While this answer is accurate, is isn't very informative.  Perhaps the OP should have asked: `What information in the .sln file is used to determine what version of Visual Studio it belongs to?`