# How can Visual Studio determine a solution file's version?

Tags: visual-studio

Think that I have two solutions: vs2009.sln and vs2010.sln. Both of solution files have the same extension (.sln) but they have different icons. And they are opened in the related version of visual studio. I wonder how does visual studio determine this?

Edit:
Visual studio version selecter is ok but i wonder how can the icon be different even the extensions are same? I used to know that every extension has only one icon in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\explorer\Shell Icons

2.Edit: I found the answer finally. If anyone wonders about that, the answer is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144122%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693562/how-does-windows-know-what-version-of-visual-studio-a-sln-file-relates-to

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't find what i am looking for on that link

Comment: It answers both your questions. The icon is determined by an icon handler shell extension and (as explained in the answers below) the VS version to open is determined by the Version Selector.

Answer (score 43):

Open your .sln file with Notepad or another text editor.  Look for `Format Version` on the first line which correlates with a Visual Studio version.  Here's some that I'm familiar with:

- Format Version 8.00 is Visual Studio 2003
- Format Version 9.00 is Visual Studio 2005
- Format Version 10.00 is Visual Studio 2008
- Format Version 11.00 is Visual Studio 2010
- Format Version 12.00 is Visual Studio 2013

Comment: You can open `Format Version 12.00` in `VS2010 SP1` also.

Comment: What about 2015 and 2017?

Comment: @rory.ap 2015, 2017, and 2019 all still use version 12.

Answer (score 11):

Solution files are text files.

The very first line contains version information.

For example, for a Visual Studio 2010 solution you will find:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
```

Additionally, when you have several different versions of Visual Studio installed, the `.sln` file goes through the Visual Studio Version Selector utility that reads this and opens the corresponding version of Visual Studio. Check the `.sln` file associations.

Comment: You can open `Format Version 12.00` in  `VS2010 SP1`

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the .sln in a notepad

the first line itself says `Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00` or 11 or whatever version it is

Comment: And the second line says something like: `# Visual Studio 14` but it uses `2010` for vs2010, `2013` for vs2013, and `14` for vs2015.  vs2010 uses `Format Version 11.00` and vs2013 and 2015 use `Format Version 12.00`.  Don't know about other versions.

Comment: vs2010 uses msvc-10.0 in boost build.