# Visual Studio 2013 crashes on opening solution: has stopped working Visual Studio use in-Time-Debugger

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, .net-framework-version

when opening any `.sln` file my Visual Studio 2013 crashes with following error:

> An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in devenv.exe

Possible Debuggers:

> New instance of Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

--> I am using 2013

This error suddenly occurred without doing anything, at least not that I am aware of. I have seen many similar problems to this but no one has solved them, yet..

**EDIT local dump**

```
    0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for WindowsBase.ni.dll
GetUrlPageData2 (WinHttp) failed: 12002.

DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
eax=168124f8 ebx=00000001 ecx=07c44ef8 edx=00f3f15c esi=168124f0 edi=00f3f154
eip=e8000000 esp=00f3ef80 ebp=00f3f00c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00210202
e8000000 ??              ???
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
e8000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: e8000000
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000008
   Parameter[1]: e8000000
Attempt to execute non-executable address e8000000

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NOSOS

PROCESS_NAME:  devenv.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000008

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  e8000000

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
vcpkg!EnvUtils::ValidateFile+9c
60ddf268 8b45c8          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp-38h]

EXECUTE_ADDRESS: ffffffffe8000000

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
+0
e8000000 ??              ???

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  524fcb34

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  12.0.21005.1

PROCESS_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  unknown

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  0.0.0.0

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  e8000000

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  bbbbbbb4

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.15063.296 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH:  fb08b3e0d26f59b745effd61c5c16cb11b294362

MODLIST_SHA1_HASH:  e077fef6b924063dd9adb146ae617873baf70a07

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

SUITE_MASK:  272

DUMP_FLAGS:  8000c07

DUMP_TYPE:  3

MISSING_CLR_SYMBOL: 0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-BS5SBSD

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  07-20-2017 16:11:36.0410

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.15063.468 x86fre

MANAGED_CODE: 1

MANAGED_ENGINE_MODULE:  clr

MANAGED_ANALYSIS_PROVIDER:  SOS

MANAGED_THREAD_ID: 8e8

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  SOS.DLL is not loaded for managed code. Analysis might be incomplete

OS_LOCALE:  DEU

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

    ID:     [0n292]
    Type:   [@ACCESS_VIOLATION]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Omit
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [0x8e8]
    Frame:  [0] : unknown!unknown

    ID:     [0n266]
    Type:   [INVALID_POINTER_EXECUTE]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [0x8e8]
    Frame:  [0] : unknown!unknown

    ID:     [0n274]
    Type:   [SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0xcc8]
    TID:    [0x8e8]
    Frame:  [0] : unknown!unknown

    ID:     [0n272]
    Type:   [INVALID_POINTER]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0xcc8]
    TID:    [0x8e8]
    Frame:  [0] : unknown!unknown

    ID:     [0n234]
    Type:   [NOSOS]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [Unspecified]
    Frame:  [0]

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_INVALID_POINTER_EXECUTE_NOSOS

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 60ddf268 to e8000000

STACK_TEXT:  
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
00f3ef7c 60ddf268 168124f8 00f3f15c 3cc66705 0xe8000000
00f3f00c 60ddf66a 00f3f07c 00f3f144 00f3f154 vcpkg!EnvUtils::ValidateFile+0x9c
00f3f180 60ddfc26 00000001 3cc66699 00000000 vcpkg!CInitializeConfigurationWorkItem::ProcessFiles+0x166
00f3f2e8 60d7c573 00000001 3cc6642d 146e3ae8 vcpkg!CInitializeConfigurationWorkItem::Initialize+0xe3f
00f3f324 60d7a609 00000001 3cc66471 07a5417c vcpkg!CMultiItemWorkItem::Initialize+0x86
00f3f378 60d385c4 07ad6e1c 00f3f410 77155da0 vcpkg!CWorkItem::ProcessPendingInitializeCalls+0xad
00f3f3b8 60d382c3 07a5417c fffffffe 14073550 vcpkg!CParserManager::OnIdle+0x3a3
00f3f474 71b84ce7 07ad6e1c fffffffe ffffffff vcpkg!CVCPackage::FDoIdle+0x1d0
00f3f4a4 71b84e0f 00000000 0104e204 00000002 msenv!SCM::FDoIdleLoop+0x122
00f3f4c8 71b84e5a ffffffff 00f3f4f8 71b849df msenv!SCM::FDoIdle+0xd5
00f3f4d4 71b849df 0104e1b8 ffffffff 066313f8 msenv!SCM_MsoStdCompMgr::FDoIdle+0x11
00f3f4f8 71b84479 066313f8 ffffffff ffffffff msenv!MainMessageLoop::DoIdle+0x1a
00f3f534 71c83083 0835d33f 00000000 0104e1b0 msenv!CMsoCMHandler::EnvironmentMsgLoop+0x12e
00f3f56c 71c82fb3 066313f8 ffffffff 0104e1b0 msenv!CMsoCMHandler::FPushMessageLoop+0x132
00f3f594 71c82f12 06614bd0 ffffffff 00000cc8 msenv!SCM::FPushMessageLoop+0xae
00f3f5b4 71c82ed9 0104e1b4 06614bd0 ffffffff msenv!SCM_MsoCompMgr::FPushMessageLoop+0x2a
00f3f5e0 71c82e1d ffffffff 0835d38f 00000000 msenv!CMsoComponent::PushMsgLoop+0x2e
00f3f670 71baf730 0835d0e7 00fa1c70 71b10000 msenv!VStudioMainLogged+0x525
00f3f698 2f73f1e2 00fa16d0 280e5cc0 00fa1c70 msenv!VStudioMain+0x7c
00f3f6d8 2f73ee26 280e53b8 77154cc0 2f74b56c devenv!util_CallVsMain+0xde
00f3f9a0 2f748734 00000000 00f74865 00000001 devenv!CDevEnvAppId::Run+0x9bc
00f3f9c8 2f748799 2f730000 00000000 00f74865 devenv!WinMain+0xbd
00f3fa14 77158744 00d00000 77158720 a9dba18e devenv!WinMainCRTStartup+0x12f
00f3fa28 778b582d 00d00000 fd9eefff 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
00f3fa70 778b57fd ffffffff 778d6386 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
00f3fa80 00000000 2f74c3e1 00d00000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  0136bd6660b54be9c6ec0b5c346ba7b7017c80cb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  43ea5823f76b450da54d29b14be5db6eb9d88bc3

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  22f3d87dbea0d43cb2ca58d96819da8f26bffe9e

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  8bc8458b

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  vcpkg!EnvUtils::ValidateFile+9c

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: vcpkg

IMAGE_NAME:  vcpkg.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5590c8c5

STACK_COMMAND:  .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NOSOS_c0000005_vcpkg.dll!EnvUtils::ValidateFile

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_INVALID_POINTER_EXECUTE_NOSOS_BAD_IP_vcpkg!EnvUtils::ValidateFile+9c

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  c0000005

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  vcpkg.dll

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  vcpkg.dll

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  vcpkg

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  vcpkg

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  EnvUtils::ValidateFile

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  EnvUtils::ValidateFile

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  9c

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  5590c8c5

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  44caac

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  12.0.40629.0

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_INVALID_POINTER_EXECUTE_NOSOS_BAD_IP_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  vcpkg.dll!EnvUtils::ValidateFile

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/devenv.exe/12.0.21005.1/524fcb34/unknown/0.0.0.0/bbbbbbb4/c0000005/e8000000.htm?Retriage=1

TARGET_TIME:  2017-07-20T14:57:52.000Z

OSBUILD:  15063

OSSERVICEPACK:  296

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt SingleUserTS

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  unknown_date

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160101.0800

BUILDLAB_STR:  WinBuild

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.15063.296

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  6ee0

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:software_nx_fault_nosos_c0000005_vcpkg.dll!envutils::validatefile

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {653be37d-7dca-4334-85f0-5ab76235b00d}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a VS2013 `.sln` file? Open the `.sln` e.g. using Notepad to see what `Format Version` it contains, and compare with this list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32753067/1220550

Comment: Yes 100% sure, it says: `Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00`

Comment: I have both version on my computer tho! @PeterB

Comment: From a CMD prompt, try running `devenv.exe /log c:\temp\VS2013.log` (using VS2013 devenv obviously). Then open the `.sln`. If it crashes again, inspect the logfile, it may reveal more details.

Comment: in which directory do I have to call this prompt? @PeterB

Comment: Depends on where it was installed, on my system the path is `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE`.

Comment: PS the log file is actually XML, an associated `.xsl` sheet is also created. Give the logfile `.xml` extension so then you can open it in a decent XML viewer or IE or Firefox to see a color-coded version of it (red = Error).

Comment: Hm your CMD prompt does not work. 1. I have to do `./devenv.exe ..` and secondly it says: These files could not be found and will not be loaded. is there sth wrong with your prompt? @PeterB

Comment: When I do: Windows and enter cmd + Enter and then go to the directory and enter your prompt I receive the operation could not be completed

Comment: However when I do: devenv.exe /log it opens Visual Studio then I try to open `.sln` it crashes again but I cannot find the /log file. @PeterB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Comment: create a crash dump and analyze the dump as I've explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046)

Comment: I have posted the outcome of `!analyze -v` but tbh I cannot really interpret that. could you help me? @magicandre1981

Comment: as I wrote run 32bit/x86 debugger. Windbg also tells this.

Comment: I have run Windbg.exe (x86)? Or what do you mean? @magicandre1981

Comment: no, you used 64bit Windbg (ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.15063.468 **amd64fre**)

Comment: Okay, I have updated it now @magicandre1981

Comment: you get a NX fault issue. this is hard to debug. VS tried to execute memory which shouldn't be executed. try to run vs in safe mode (without any 3rd party addons) if it happens here, too he can't fix it. Also try VS2017 community edition, here MS still fixes bugs

Comment: I have VS2015 as well and when opening it with 2015 it works, however I need to use VS2013... it just suddently stopped working...  @magicandre1981

Comment: why do you need VS2013? license issues?

Comment: No because it is the project from someone else and if I use 2015 there are errors occuring... in safe mode it does not work either. I think it should be a simple problem. earlier today it was still working but now it suddenly crashes... @magicandre1981

Comment: make a reboot, also 10.0.15063.296  is outdated, install the latest update from this months patchday, maybe it s fixed here. you should fix the errors in newer VS versions

Comment: It is opening when I use VS 2015, but I get compile errors since the project is based on VS2013 and uses platform tool version = 120 rather than 140. @magicandre1981

Comment: I have rebooted 100 times already :D @magicandre1981

Comment: load sln in VS2015, open the properties of the projects and change toolversion from 120 to 140. This is simple, takes 10s. And latest win10 v1703 update is [KB4025342](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4025342) (OS Build 15063.483)

Comment: any update? have you changed the platform in vs2015? does it compile? does it fix your issue?

Comment: Hm, I reinstalled VS 2013 and it works now. @magicandre1981

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem. Every time I open my Visual Studio 2013, with or without a solution in it, it will crash and show:

> Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working

It was solved by:

1. Disconnect your PC from any internet connection,
2. Open Visual Studio 2013. In this state, you are able to open your VS 2013 without any issue, but it will have the problem again when you connect to internet,
3. Logout your account from Visual Studio 2013,
4. Connect to internet again

In my case, it doesn't really a matter if I logout my account from my VS 2013, therefore it fixed the issue.

Comment: Awesome ! Worked for me. I just had this issue while at work and it was driving me crazy. Is this a coincidence that you answered only a few hours ago ? Or did you get this bug after the latest WINDOWS update ? I believe that might be the cause of all this ...

Comment: @PrisecaruAlin Glad it fixed your issue. Yes, it happened just this morning. Strange, because yesterday it worked fine and I didn't do any update both on Visual Studio and Windows. My colleague also had the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache directory
3. Restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Guys When you are Facing this type issue Visual Studio When you Start It's Getting This Type "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 has Stopped Working"

NOTE: Please check when you disconnect the internet VS 2013 It's Working Again You Start Internet Again the same Problem.

**In that Case, You Can Log Out Microsoft ID Which you have logged into Visual Studio 2013**

Then Problem Resolved,